# Is there any way to check character input from a readline is a number?

Tags: r, regex, readline, numeric

I´d like to ask if there is a way to check whether the result of a `readline()` is numeric.

Since I need to do mathematical operations with these inputs, any character other than numbers and "." will destroy the program.

Do I have to work on the input string letter by letter to check each character? Or there is some elegant way to do it?

Comment: The value of `readline()` is "A character vector of length one" (quoting `?readline`). Why don't you just wrap it in `as.numeric()` and make your program robust to `NA` inputs?

Comment: @apom the problem of using as.numeric is that it changes the inputs by default, for example if the input is "2,8" instead of "2.8", the result would be the number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `readline()` always returns a character string. You can deal with this in two ways:

- using brute force with `as.numeric()`: this will return anything that cannot be converted to numeric as `NA`. You can then check with `is.na()` to see whether this worked.
- using regular expressions. With `grepl()` you get a `TRUE/FALSE` value for every element of the vector, indicating whether or not some character has been found.

Try the following:

```
x <- readline("give a number: ")
if(grepl("[^[:digit:]\\.-]",x)) stop("This is not a number") else "Hooray"
```

Works as follows:

```
> x <- readline("give a number: ")
give a number: -23.48
> if(grepl("[^[:digit:]\\.-]",x)) stop("This is not a number") else "Hooray"
[1] "Hooray"
> x <- readline("give a number: ")
give a number: -25.645)
> if(grepl("[^[:digit:]\\.-]",x)) stop("This is not a number") else "Hooray"
Error: This is not a number
```

If you want to thoroughly check whether something is formatted as a number (including scientific notation), this is a classic regular expression to test it with:

```
"ˆ[+-]?(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)([eE][+-]?\\d+)?$"
```

So that would be:

```
x <- readline("give a number: ")
isnumber <- grepl("ˆ[+-]?(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)([eE][+-]?\\d+)?$",x)
if(!isnumber) stop("X is not a number") else "Hooray"
```

Comment: the regexp has some potential holes; what about `"13.234.2342"` as a test case ... ? is `+23` a legal number?  How about `1.0e23`  ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker That's all tackled with the second regex.